# Use LDAP to store only username and password

Tags: authentication, ldap, passwords

**Context:**
I am working on an Authentication Service in the backend of my application. The idea is to authenticate through LDAP but only using username and password. I should also be able to Create, Modify and Delete any user.

**Problem:**
I have a local LDAP server to test and I can't find a way to store only the username and password without having to create a new Object Class. Is there any way to do this the standard way?

**Things I have tried:**

- Using the inetOrgPerson Object Class. It did not work because CN and SN are mandatory attributes and thus I can't create the user without them.

Comment: The CN *is* the username in `inetOrgPerson`, and everybody has a surname. What’s your objection to setting it?

Comment: Because I only need username and password. The rest of the user's information is going to a SQL DB, while the authenticacion has to be done through LDAP.

Comment: I suggest that’s back to front. LDAP is designed to hold user information. SQL not really.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you but sadly it is not my call :(

Answer (score 1):

LDAP is for directory servers, which has a directory structure. Every object is at some location in the directory structure, and the CN forms part of the location in the directory. It's mandatory and there's no way around it.